# Is there a reason hyphen/dash is not allowed in store codes?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, store-code

Both M1 and M2 don't allow hyphens or dashes in its store codes. There is backend validation against it. However, it is not clear why. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe the dev just did not know how to make the regex :) Truly, I do not know but I am curious as it is a request I often have.

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation I can find is:

> A code is an identifier and normally represents one word. Therefore it consist of characters of the word-character class. Also not starting with a number sounds like a named identifier. So your two-words use-case is not applicable on the code, as it represents one word. Therefore no non-word-characters are allowed.
>
> So you've found you can use a single word within the path-component of the URI and you've found out that the store-code is not suitable for two words. An URL-rewrite and output filter can handle this.

Taken from Hakre's comment about Magento 1 but I suspect the same logic is added to Magento 2 -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353636/magento-dash-in-store-code